# Use Weka from ImageJ macro: 'path' is required but unset

Tags: macros, weka, imagej

I have tried Calling Weka from an ImageJ(Fiji) macro:

```bs
run("Trainable Weka Segmentation", "open=C:\\input\\test.tif inputfile=C:\input\test.tif path=[Ljava.lang.String;@77e655d8");
```

But when I run that I get an error message: 'path' is required but unset

This line is exactly the line I get when recording a macro and opening test.tif when the Trainable Weka Segmentation dialog starts. I have also tried without the inputfile and/or path variables.

How should I call "Trainable Weka Segmentation"?

Comment: I wonder how you got the `inputfile` and `path` parameters in the recorder. How did proceed exactly when starting Trainable Weka Segmentation?

Comment: When running the Trainable Weka Segmentation from the plugins menu instead of from a macro you get to select an image initially, and that is how the inputfile and path parameters come into the recorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Trainable Weka Segmentation* plugin doesn't adhere to the macro recording conventions of ImageJ, mainly because of its complex structure.

However, the correct way to interact with the plugin by macro scripting is described extensively in its [documentation on the Fiji wiki](http://fiji.sc/Trainable_Weka_Segmentation#Macro_language_compatibility). In summary, you need to something like:

```bs
open("C:\\input\\test.tif"); // open your file
run("Trainable Weka Segmentation"); // then start the plugin

call("trainableSegmentation.Weka_Segmentation.loadClassifier", "C:\\path\\to\\your\\classifier.model");

call("trainableSegmentation.Weka_Segmentation.getProbability");
```